# What cache files are deleted during Safe Boot?

Tags: macos, startup, safe-mode

According to https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201262 a safe boot will perform the following:

> - Verifies your startup disk, and attempts to repair directory issues if needed
> - Loads only required kernel extensions
> - Prevents Startup Items and Login Items from opening automatically
> - Disables user-installed fonts
> - Deletes font caches, Kernel cache and other system cache files

Apple as usual is somewhat vague.  Does anyone have a list of the exact cache files deleted and where to find them?

Why I need this:  I have two labs of iMacs where after a week or so of student use, they will freeze and when rebooted get stuck at 100% of the progress bar. About 80% of the time a safe boot fixes them (the remaining I usually end up wiping).  I've looked at /Library/Caches and /System/Library/Caches before and after a safe boot and there appears to be no change.

Any clues what cache files I should look at next?  If I can pinpoint the culprit, I can design a manual purge of this file and hopefully keep my uptime of these machines beyond a week.

Comment: Forgot to include, all machines are currently running 10.11.6

Comment: I seem to have found a resolution to my specific problem, but I'd like to keep this question open as it seems beneficial if someone could answer it.